# What is the best way to manage a large amount of static data in Java?

Tags: java

I am beginning work on a side project and I am trying to outline the structure of the program I am writing. The basic concept is a GUI application for quizzing on spanish verb conjugations. I want it to function kind of like this website:(https://www.magistrula.com/latin/charts?cap=adv&quiz=decl&mac=essMac)

In Spanish, there are many irregular verbs and stem changes that would make it difficult to have a list of infinitives and then generate all the forms automatically. Ultimately, there will be hundreds of verbs many of which have unique forms. I would like each word to have every form saved statically. Should I use a JSON file, a database, or many static classes? I am unsure.

My first thought was to create many static classes, but I feel that wold be creating far more work for myself than necessary. Everything in this project should be local and run without a network connection.

Comment: Database or resource files. This certainly has nothing to do with [tag:oop].

Comment: Why do you want to make it all "static"?

Comment: _[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)_ databases are very fast.

Comment: Database.  Don’t try to keep it all in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by “static” you mean the `static` keyword in Java, as in `static final` constants… don't do that.

You *could* do that. But as the Comments say, an alternative approach is likely wiser.

One issue is that `static` data in Java, once loaded is forever loaded. You cannot purge any static members of a class after that class loads.

Another issue is that any change to your verb data means recompiling your app. That seems silly just to fix a typo.

Instead, load your data as needed from an external source. For any one use of your app, your user is unlikely to need every form of every conjugation of every verb.

I would suggest you start by loading from simple text files. Later, you may  (or may not) decide that a database is better, such as [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(database)).

---

You may want to learn about the common “Repository” idiom in Java where you separate the code needing the data from the code fetching the data.

- The code needing data calls upon an interface.
- The code fetching the data is in a class implementing that interface.

So you can start with an implementation class for accessing files. Later you can try an alternative implementation class for accessing a database. You can swap between these implementations without altering the code that needs the data.

Another benefit: This approach facilitates testing by enabling dummy implementation classes with a bit of hard-coded data. Indeed, you may want to start your work with such a dummy-data implementation, to get your app going to work out details of your user-interface.

Answer (score 1):

Database is overkill - it's essentially static data that will eventually stabilise. You don't need the headache of DB code, where it will reside, how to back it up, etc.

Store the word information in a resource file in the repo if your project, include it in your jar file and load it at start up.

The amount of data is actually small - 100K words tops, and of those only some are verbs, and of those only some are irregular. Design your data to minimise its size.

Choose whatever format is easiest for you to read and edit. Good options are CSV, JSON and YAML - all choices are good.

Answer (score 0):

I often run into these situations, that when I design some code structure, I don`t know where to start. Whether to create a whole bunch of interfaces or super classes or not.

I tried to use oop for this situation, but it will end up with a lot of classes, I think you should leave oop to end.

From experience, I recommend "starting from very small things".

1. put them in static fields in a class like you said, and after some time you may find a more suitable way, whether to loading them once from file, DB or some other approaches seems fine.
2. use `enums` like below, this example where I split some verbs into two categories may not suit your case.

```
enum BeBeedBeenVerbs {

    IS("is", "was", "been"),
    ARE("are", "were", "been"),
    WAS("is", "was", "been"),
    WERE("are", "were", "been"),
    ;

    private String be;
    private String beed;
    private String been;

    BeBeedBeenVerbs(String be, String beed, String been) {
        this.be = be;
        this.beed = beed;
        this.been = been;
    }
}

enum BeBeedVerbsEnum {
    HAVE("have", "had"),
    HAS("has", "had"),
    HAD("have", "had"),
    ;

    private String be;
    private String beed;

    BeBeedVerbsEnum(String be, String beed) {
        this.be = be;
        this.beed = beed;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't 'leave OOP to [the] end', but it has no applicability here.

Comment: can you explain why OOP has no applicability here?